# Android: cannot animate() child TextView of a custom RecyclerView item

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a custom `FoldingCell` layout for each item in a `recyclerViiew`. I have a child `textView` in the folding cell which I want to animate if a certain condition is true like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // if this item is unfolded only bind the unfolded child views
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
            holder.cell.unfold(true);
            bindUnfoldedState(holder, holder.getLayoutPosition());
        }else{
            // else bind the child views visibel when folded
            holder.cell.fold(true);
            bindFoldedState(holder, holder.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }

    public void bindUnfoldedState(ViewHolder holder, int position){

        // classes holds all the elements in the recyclerView
        myClass class = classes.get(position);

            if(classes.isbuttonEnabled()){
                Log.i("BIND","entered");

                // after entering here, animation does not happen the first time
                holder.priceText.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500);
                holder.priceText.animate().translationY(-38).setDuration(1000);
                holder.buttonText.animate().translationY(38).setDuration(1000);
            }else {
               // reset animation if button is false

               holder.priceText.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(500);
               holder.priceText.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
               holder.buttonText.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(500);
            }

            // setting custom button handler here . . .      
    }
```

I am calling `onItemChanged()` after I do some calculations in a fragment that will show in  the `textPrice` view. Therefore onItemChanged() will invoke `onBindViewHolder` and do animations is `isButtonEnabled` is true which i am making sure it is by using my `setButtonEnabled(true)` method like below:

```
 // ok is a button in this dialog fragment 
 ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        myclass.setButtonEnabled(true);
        // this is them setting the text to textPrice
        myclass.setPrice(55);
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(Position);
    }
}
```

the above snippet is part of a different fragment - dialog fragment that appears above the `recyclerview`.

the problem is that onBindViewHolder is being called and the animation condition is being entered but the animation is not appearing. on pressing the "ok" button again - therefore invoking `onItemChanged()` again - the animation happens.

Why is it not happening the first time?

when I initially tried this with a `listView` it worked as expected so it probably has nothing to do with the layout but something that has to do with the recyclerView/viewHolder/adapter